# A looped fetch request returns an error before the last item

Tags: javascript

I have a loop that goes through an array of locations and retrieves the current weather at the locations in the array. But for some reason I get TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null, before the last request works.

Whereas all the ones before have worked correctly. Really not sure why it would go wrong here.

```
const getData = () => {
   for (const country in weatherCountries) {
      console.log(country);
      fetch(`${baseUrl}?lat=${weatherCountries[country].lat}&lon=${weatherCountries[country].long}&APPID=${appId}`)
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(data => {
            conditions = data.weather[0].main;
            temperature = data.main.temp - 273.15;
            temperature = Math.round(temperature);
            document.getElementById(weatherCountries[country].name).innerHTML = `<h5>Current Weather</h5>
               <table>
                  <tr><th>Conditions:</th><th>Temperature:</th></tr>
                  <tr><td>${conditions}</td><td>${temperature}</td></tr>
               </table>`;
         })
   }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(weatherCountries[country].name)` returns `null`... So the country's name is not found as an id of an element on your page.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap with an if condition checking for the element so that if the country is not in the page it doesn't crash and continues with the next country:

```
let countryElement = document.getElementById(weatherCountries[country].name);
if (countryElement) {
    countryElement.innerHTML = `<h5>Current Weather</h5>
    ...
} else {
    console.log('The country: ' + country + ' is not found');
}
```

And console log the country so you can check in the browser's console in which countries do you have the error to prevent them from happening.

Comment: Sure, that prevents the error from happening, but that doesn't fix the problem...

Answer (score 1):

One of the elements doesn't exist `weatherCountries[country].name` in DOM, I would recommend you to confirm that the element before the last has the right id of the 
`weatherCountries[country].name`.

Or you can avoid the error by

```
.then(data => {
            conditions = data.weather[0].main;
            temperature = data.main.temp - 273.15;
            temperature = Math.round(temperature);
            element = document.getElementById(weatherCountries[country].name);
            if(element) {
             element.innerHTML = `<h5>Current Weather</h5>
               <table>
                  <tr><th>Conditions:</th><th>Temperature:</th></tr>
                  <tr><td>${conditions}</td><td>${temperature}</td></tr>
               </table>`;
             }
         })
```

Comment: Sure, that prevents the error from happening, but that doesn't fix the problem...